# Foreign key issue in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create table with FK, but I got the error below inserting the SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE appointment(
    appointment_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    patient_id     MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED,
    doctor_id      TINYINT UNSIGNED,
    date           TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    start_time     TIME NOT NULL,
    end_time       TIME NOT NULL,
    medical_report TEXT,
    supplement_id    SMALLINT,


    CONSTRAINT pk_appointment PRIMARY KEY (appointment_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_appointment_patient_id FOREIGEN KEY(patient_id) REFERENCES patient(patient_id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_appointment_doctor_id  FOREIGEN KEY(doctor_id) REFERENCES doctor(doctor_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_appointment_medicine_id FOREIGEN KEY(supplement_id) REFERENCES medicine(medicine_id)
);
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGEN KEY(patient_id) REFERENCES patient(patient_id), CONSTRAINT fk_appointm' at line 13
```

Someone help me please!

Comment: Well, you have a BIG typo in your code: "FOREIGEN KEY" should be "FOREIGN KEY".

Comment: It's **FOREIGN KEY**, not **FOREIGEN**.

Comment: Yes. I say it. Syntax error. But after corrected it. I have a new Error:
Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE appointment(
    appointment_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    patient_id     MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED,
    doctor_id      TINYINT UNSIGNED,
    date           TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    start_time     TIME NOT NULL,
    end_time       TIME NOT NULL,
    medical_report TEXT,
    supplement_id    SMALLINT,


    CONSTRAINT pk_appointment PRIMARY KEY (appointment_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_appointment_patient_id FOREIGN  KEY(patient_id) REFERENCES patient(patient_id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_appointment_doctor_id  FOREIGN  KEY(doctor_id) REFERENCES doctor(doctor_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_appointment_medicine_id FOREIGN  KEY(supplement_id) REFERENCES medicine(medicine_id)
);
```